# Which light linux distribution allows to connect via RDP from login screen

Tags: linux, login, remote-desktop

I would like to reactivate my old laptop and configure it in a way it will connect and login to other computer via Remote Desktop Protocol from login screen (e.g. to Windows 10).

Do you know of any light linux distro that will have such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Puppy Linux maybe the choice... or Arch linux but Arch is a little bit more complex.
Puppy il ubuntu based.

[edit]: sorry, what do you mean "it will connect and login to other computer via Remote Desktop Protocol from login screen." I think you have to run a rdp client on your laptop and so you can login on other computer

Comment: I mean that I don't need to login to my account locally, just to have simple way to login via RDP to other machine after the start of my old laptop.

Comment: Ok you have to run rdp client in full screen mode in your laptop. You can also use teamviewer... take a look http://www.ubuntumanual.org/posts/367/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-in-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. 
I think this might be the solution: set up your light system to login to local preconfigured account that starts rdp client in full screen mode.

Comment: Please find configuration for TinyCore as RDP thin client: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_nCG0r74PU